# Bypass okHttp Cache to get a network response and then update the cache

Tags: android, http, retrofit, okhttp, http-caching

I am caching the HTTP response Using Retrofit2 and OKHttp.
Here is my code:

```
    int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    Cache cache = new Cache(application.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().
cache(cache).addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor).build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
```

I am getting the response headers Cache-control and Expires from our backend REST API's.

Now i want to get the server Response by bypassing the the Expires Header.
Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add this header to your HTTP request:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

You can do this with Retrofit’s `@Header` or with an OkHttp [interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors).

Comment: whenever i required to refresh the data i will call the server but refreshed data also should be cached for next time until i want to refresh the data.